# AWK, split content in files if pattern at specific column matchs

Tags: regex, awk

Good day,

I was wondering how to split a matrix into files if pattern at specific column match.

**Pattern**: when find zero at second column, split.

So far I have done:

```
cat file | awk -FS"\t" '$2==0 {close("result"f);f++}{print $0 > "result"f}'
```

**Input**

```
1   2
2   3
4   0
5   6
7   0
```

**Expected output**

```
File 1
1   2
2   3
4   0

File 2
5   6
7   0
```

Thank in advance for any clue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -v n=1 '{print>("file-" n)} $2==0 {n++}' input
```

Explanation:

- From your input data, there appears to be no need to set the field separator to a tab.  By default, `awk` splits fields on any whitespace, tabs included.
- `-v n=1`

  The name of the output file is determined by the variable `n`.  We start it at `1`.
- `{print>("file-" n)}`

  This prints the current line to a file whose name depends on `n`.
- `$2==0 {n++}`

  If the second column is zero, we increment `n` so that the next line goes to a new file.

Answer (score 1):

`-FS"\t"` isn't doing what you think it is. awk sees that as `-F 's\t'` that is you are setting `FS` to `s<tab>`.

You want `-F"\t"` or `-v FS="\t"`.

You also need to print out the current line before you close the old file.

Comment: :( sorry to don't see that mistake. Thanks and have a good day ( :